# android/data/com. folders

Tags: photos

While searching for `.jpg` images that seem to be scattered ALL OVER my Galaxy Note 10.1 (2014), I discovered that, when connected to my Win7 PC, I can see `.jpg` images (my own photos with my unique naming system), in the `android/data/com.*` folders.  Some of the photos can be accessed; others say "corrupted or too large to be viewed."

I understand that some folders contain app specific data or thumbnail caches (I'm not touching those), but some are in VERY ODD places, for example, an entire folder of "Friends" photos is found under `android/data/com.dictionary`. Almost EVERY `android/data/com.*` folder has one or more of my photos in it (random), even folders that have NO CONNECTION whatsoever to photo editing or management.
Even with "see hidden folders" enabled, they are NOT visible when navigating the tablet folder manager.

I keep ALL my photo folders on my SD card, the above "issue" only appears in Device storage.

Can anyone explain this?